# Is there any reason *not* to run HAProxy in a Docker container?

Tags: haproxy, docker, containers

Will performance and/or stability suffer if I run HAProxy (or Nginx) in a container vs installing it directly on the host?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a good SO answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149994/684908 on the subject of performance. The tl;dr is that the NAT (port-forwarding in some cases) introduces some latency. Though, it is likely negligible at smaller scales.

I run HAProxy as a container in production with port-forwarding through the Docker NAT bridge. The application and HAProxy was originally running on bare-metal. Any latency or overhead that might have been introduced by Docker is too negligible to tell.

Answer (score 3):

The chief concern should be that you will have to wait for the container to be updated before getting any security, feature, or bugfix patches. You can't just run `yum`/`apt-get`/`yast upgrade` on the host, you need to either rebuild the container yourself, or wait for someone else to.

Comment: i agree.. making config changes would be a giant headache.. what I've done is run haproxy on the host and it proxies connections into docker containers.

Comment: Thanks. Would you expect a difference in performance though?

Comment: No noticable difference, aside from maybe a tiny bit of extra memory space for the Dockerized libraries.